# MooTools get Classname in Class (not CSS)?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using the JavaScript Framework MooTools in which it is possible to create classes similar to Object-Orientation.

I dont know if it is somehow possible to alert the classname 'TestClass' within the class.

```
var TestClass = new Class({
    Extends: Module,
    initialize: function() {
        //constructor which is called and should alert the Classname itself
                alert(this.classname); (pseudocode)
    }
});
```

Someone has an idea?

Thx in advance!

Comment: yeah but might be solved in mootools diffrent :S

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of a Mootools class from within](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837729/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-mootools-class-from-within)

Comment: @nwellnhof this won't work in mootools > 1.3 as $H is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy as a workaround but a Class can be anonymous (like a function) and reflection is meaningless then.

Compare the(a) host object's enumerables with the instance's constructor. Not a cheap thing but still. Won't work very well if you use deep namespaces, for example: `window.App.admin.controllers.view.Login` since you'd need to either recursively look for it or know it's hosted by `window.App.admin.controllers.view`

```
// define the class in the current scope / global object
this.foo = new Class();

// directly into scope
var Foo = new Class();

// define the class in a namespace
var namespace = {
    bar: new Class()
};

// get the variable class name we need to use from any source into a variable...
var dynamic = 'foo';

// make the instances
var instance1 = new this[dynamic]();
var instance2 = new namespace.bar();
var instance3 = new Foo();

function getClassNameOfInstance(mootoolsClassInstance, context) {
    // query the context (this or custom object) for the instance we are working with
    return Object.keyOf(context || this, mootoolsClassInstance.constructor);
}

// use it on the global object
console.log("instance1 is: ", getClassNameOfInstance(instance1)); // foo

// use it on the namespace object
console.log("instance2 is: ", getClassNameOfInstance(instance2, namespace)); // foo

// use it on the current scope. 
console.log("instance3 is: ", getClassNameOfInstance.call(this, instance3)); // Foo
```

see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/c8pR4/

here is an example anonymous Class, a useful pattern if you don't plan on instantiating something more than once:

`var instance = new (new Class({ ... }))(args);`

I did write about this a while ago - http://fragged.org/working-with-dynamic-class-names-in-mootools_1395.html

A better / more sensible approach will be to manually give IDs to all Classes that need them, eg:

```
var Request.CORS = new Class('Request.CORS', { ... });
var i = new Request.CORS();
i.$className; // 'Request.CORS'
```

this is a pattern common in AMD (`define('id', [deps], fn)`), DOJO (`declare('id', [deps], obj)`) etc.

To extend your MooTools to support that you could do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rnbW6/5/ - which will add a `Request.JSON.prototype.$className` property or getter (via `Object.defineProperty` config if avail).

If you go that route, you can even do a Class factory so your dependency resolution can be like `Class.require('Request.CORS')` and you won't ever need to save your definitions into global variables outside of the reference in your Class closure.

Comment: this works fine, but i dont want to have this call from outside, i need to have it inside that class-instance (called from constructor)...

Comment: you can extend your Class type constructor to support an optional class id (like in AMD `define('id', [], fn);` or DOJO's `declare`. eg. http://jsfiddle.net/rnbW6/2/ - and there is nothing to stop you from decorating your prototype either to be able to call the method above in my original response.

Comment: in fact, here is an immutable id as a getter via `defineProperty` - http://jsfiddle.net/rnbW6/5/ - this implicit ID pattern is not as DRY but it is far more versatile and much more common.